# Invalid oracle procedure parameters list

Tags: oracle, vb6, ado

I have oracle procedure described like that:

```
create or replace procedure "TEST_PROC" (
  param1 IN VARCHAR2, 
  param2 IN VARCHAR2, 
  output OUT BOOLEAN) is 
begin 
  output := True; 
end;
```

I have vb6 code that populates in/out parameters like that:

```
...
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA; ...
...

cmd.CommandText = "TEST_PROC"
cmd.CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc

Dim v As String
v = "some-value"        
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 200, 1, 255, v)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("param2", 200, 1, 255, v)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("output", 11, 2, 1, 0)

cmd.Execute
```

But it breaks on Execute with error:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_PROC'
```

What is wrong here ? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: At first glance I would say it's because you are trying to pass a parameter in to an 'OUT' variable, the function is only expecting 2 inputs and it looks as though 3 are been passed, could you explain what the function is supposed to do please?

Comment: It's going to get filter criteria (2 strings) as input parameters and return if record is present

Comment: Do you have an SQL query to which these 2 filter criteria are being applied please?

Comment: Thank you, Matt! DCookie found out the reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is with the BOOLEAN data type in the procedure. BOOLEAN is not a database type, it's a PL/SQL type, and ADO only knows about database types. To test this out, replace your BOOLEAN output parameter with a NUMBER or VARCHAR, and see if you can get a result back from that. ALternatively, wrap this procedure in another procedure that translates the BOOLEAN into another type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WRAP_PROC (param1 IN VARCHAR2
                                     , param2 IN VARCHAR2
                                     , output OUT INTEGER) IS
  v_out BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  test_proc(param1, param2, v_out);
  IF v_out = TRUE THEN
    output := 1;
  ELSE
    output := 0;
  END IF;
END wrap_proc;
/
```